# Kotlin date parsing is not working properly

Tags: java, kotlin, java-time, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

So I have been looking up on how to properly parse an incoming datetime, problem is that this string contains the zone as well which apparently can't be parsed for some reason.
To give an example of the incoming date time string:
`2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000`

Now I tried to the following:

```kt
var dateTimeString = "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000"
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
var date = LocalDate.parse(dateTimeString, formatter)
```

I tried replacing Z with nothing and with ZZZZ, but that didn't work I assume it doesn't work because of the plus or minus sign not being present. FYI, I receive the date in this format because of the Microsoft Graph API when retrieving the calendar events.

Any idea as to how this date should be formatted properly?

Edit: This comes from Microsoft Graph. Basically they give like a date as an object:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

This is the page of the documentation that explains this date object:  [dateTimeTimeZone resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0).

## Update:

I was finally able to solve this date issue, what I did was the following:

```kt
var inputDateTime = "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000"
var inputTimeZone = "UTC"
var zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(
    inputDateTime,
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of(inputTimeZone))
).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
```

This way, the date would be converted correctly to the right time zone and to the right Date/Time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to parse with `Z`? I cannot see any zone-offset in `"2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000"`.

Comment: timezone is the last 4 digits

Comment: There's no plus and no minus sign, how would this resolve to a valid time zone? Ok, `0000` would be UTC, but what about other zones?

Comment: I know but this comes from Microsoft Graph it's not something I am making up. Basically they give like a date as an object: 
`"start": {"dateTime": "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000", "timeZone": "UTC"}`

Comment: This is the page of the documentation that explains this date object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: That does not look like a standard representation, I really doubt the last 4 digits represent a zone, you even get the zone separately as `String`. Since it's 0 here, you could just parse it without a zone, but I wouldn't do.

Comment: Do you have an example that is not in UTC? Oh, and **where in that documentation** is the talk about the last 4 digits? I cannot find it...

Comment: No otherwise I would have been sure if the last 4 digits actually represent time zone offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your Date-Time string does not have timezone information

Your Date-Time string, `2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000` does not have timezone information. The `.0000000` represents the fraction of a second and as of now, `java.time` is capable of handling up to 9 digits of precision (i.e. nanosecond of precision).

Since it does not have timezone information, it represents a local Date-Time and hence should be parsed into `LocalDateTime`.

#### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` for your Date-Time string

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Your Date-Time string is already in the ISO 8601 format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        var dateTimeString = "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000";
        var ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-05T10:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/FqHb1f)

#### How to get `ZonedDateTime` out of the `LocalDateTime` instance?

You can use [`LocalDateTime#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert attach a `ZoneId` to a `LocalDateTime` resulting into a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
```

**Note**: If you need an `Instant`, you can get it from this instant of  `ZonedDateTime` e.g.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline, normally represented in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) time. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As I can see from docs you've provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
dateTime    String  A single point of time in a combined date and time representation ({date}T{time}; for example, 2017-08-29T04:00:00.0000000).
timeZone    String  Represents a time zone, for example, "Pacific Standard Time". See below for more possible values.
```

`dateTime` object has no zone encoded. And all 7 zeroes represent fractions of a second. In such case it's regular `ISO_DATE_TIME` and you don't need to create your own formatter.

The following code should work

```
var dateTimeString = "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000"
var date = LocalDate.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, first time I encountered such a format, usually dates only have 3 digits to represent the fractions of seconds, so I assumed the other 4 digits must have been the time zone offset

Answer (score 2):

For the case that the last 4 digits in your example `String` are not representing a time zone:

Parse it without a formatter (no need since it would be perfect ISO standard if the last 4 digits are just additional fractions of second), but also **consider the time zone** you get with the JSON:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    // the time String from JSON
    var dateTimeString = "2021-10-05T10:00:00.0000000"
    // the zone from JSON (may not always work, but does with UTC)
    var timeZone = "UTC"
    // create the zone from the timezone String
    var zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone)
    // then parse the time String using plain LocalDateTime and add the zone afterwards
    var zdt: ZonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString).atZone(zoneId)
    // print some results
    println("Full ZonedDateTime: ${zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)}")
    println("(Local)Date only:   ${zdt.toLocalDate()}")
}
```

```
Full ZonedDateTime: 2021-10-05T10:00:00Z[UTC]
(Local)Date only:   2021-10-05
```

Please note that parsing the [time zones currently supported by Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones) won't work this easy (except from `UTC`), but the [time zones supported by the calendar API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0#additional-time-zones) are (mostly) sufficient for the creation of a `java.time.ZoneId`.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement: Your documentation mentions `Pacific Standard Time` as a time zone string that may come as part of your MS Graph dateTimeTimeZone. I don’t think the other answers can handle that one, so I should like to show how you do handle it in Java.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter ZONE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

static ZoneId parseZone(String timeZoneString) {
    try {
        return ZoneId.from(ZONE_FORMATTER.parse(timeZoneString));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return ZoneId.of(timeZoneString);
    }
}
```

I believe that this handles the strings mentioned in the documentation and also `UTC` from your question. I am demonstrating just three different ones:

```
    String[] msTimeZoneStrings = { "UTC", "Pacific Standard Time", "Pacific/Honolulu" };
    for (String zoneString : msTimeZoneStrings) {
        ZoneId zid = parseZone(zoneString);
        System.out.format("%-21s parsed to %s%n", zoneString, zid);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> UTC                   parsed to UTC
> Pacific Standard Time parsed to America/Los_Angeles
> Pacific/Honolulu      parsed to Pacific/Honolulu
> ```

In the formatter I use `zzzz` is for time zone name like `Pacific Standard Time`. My parse method tries this formatter first. It fails for `UTC` and `Pacific/Honolulu`. When the `DateTimeParseException` is caught, the method next tries the `ZoneId.of` method also used in the other answers. It handles `UTC` and all the time zone ID sin *region/city* format mentioned in the documentation.

Combine the `ZoneId` obtained from my method with the parsed `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime` the way that deHaar is already showing in their answer.